# how to pass file as argument to gulp task

Tags: gruntjs, gulp

I need some help regarding my gulp task.

I have gulp karma task and I want to pass karma config file as a argument to that task. 
I am able to achieve this grunt. Like in grunt , we can use

`grunt.option("file")`

and we can called grunt task as

```
grunt taskName --file=myFileName
```

So How Can I achieve same with gulp?

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing in gulp to parse command line arguments for you.
You can use node's global `process.argv` directly if you feel like it. 
I like to use the [yargs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yargs) module to handle arguments in my gulpfiles.

```
var args = require('yargs').argv;
var karmaFile = argv.file; // for the argument --file="myFileName"
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @kombucha's answer, here's an example of how to use process.argv. If in your case you passed:

```
gulp taskName --file myFileName
```

(without the '=' ) then the below would retrieve the file value:

```
var filename, i = process.argv.indexOf("--file");
if(i>-1) {
    filename = process.argv[i+1];
}
```

It should be simple enough to turn the above into a generic function for retrieving command-line values. I have used this before to good effect:

```
function getCLValue(name) {
    var i = process.argv.indexOf(name);
    return (i>-1) ? process.argv[i+1] : null;
}
```